# Change a checkbox text and function based on checkbox.checkstate in groupbox

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to teach myself VB .net and as my first project I'm trying to design a form that functions much like the checkboxes in Gmail.  Tons of checkboxes in a group and one checkbox that sits outside the group to select/deselect those within.

I've gotten far enough to have that master checkbox do its thing, but I would really like to have the form notice whenever anything within the groupbox is checked by the user, then to change its text & function automatically.  The code I came up with to change the text works, but I can't figure out where to put it:

```
For Each ctrl As CheckBox In GroupBox1.Controls
        If ctrl.CheckState = 1 Then
            CheckBox1.Text = "Deselect All"
        End If
    Next
```

I can link the code to a button push or a checkbox change, but I'd like it to be automatic since having the user click something to run the check defeats the purpose.  I tried double clicking the groupbox and placing the code there but it does nothing.  Also tried double clicking the form background but it does nothing there either.  Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have probably noticed, there may be a few different places where you need to do this.   To reuse a piece of functionality, create a new method that does that job.  Double-click the form, and place this just before the  End Class:

```
''' <summary>Update each of the CheckBoxes that in the same GroupBox</summary>
''' <param name="sender">The CheckBox that was clicked.</param>
''' <param name="e"></param>
''' <remarks>It is assumed that only checkboxed that live in a GroupBox will use this method.</remarks>
Public Sub UpdateCheckBoxState(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

    'Get the group box that the clicked checkbox lives in 
    Dim parentGroupBox As System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox = DirectCast(DirectCast(sender, System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox).Parent, System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox)

    For Each ctrl As System.Windows.Forms.Control In parentGroupBox.Controls
        'Only process the checkboxes (in case there's other stuff in the GroupBox as well)
        If TypeOf ctrl Is System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox Then

            'This control is a checkbox.  Let's remember that to make it easier.
            Dim chkBox As System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox = DirectCast(ctrl, System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox)

            If chkBox.CheckState = 1 Then
                chkBox.Text = "Deselect All"
            Else
                chkBox.Text = "Select All"
            End If

        End If  ' - is CheckBox
    Next ctrl

End Sub
```

Now you have a method that will do what you want, you need to connect it to each CheckBox that you want to manage.  Do this by adding the following code in The Form_Load event:

```
    AddHandler CheckBox1.CheckedChanged, AddressOf UpdateCheckBoxState
    AddHandler CheckBox2.CheckedChanged, AddressOf UpdateCheckBoxState
    ...
```

So now the same method will handle the ClickChanged method of all of your connected checkboxes.

You can also update the checkBoxes in addition to when the user clicks it by calling the Method `UpdateCheckBoxState(`*CheckBoxThatYouWantToProgramaticallyUpdate*`, Nothing)` perhaps in Form_Load, or elsewhere.

Comment: Thank you so much, I was actually looking for the correct method that would launch the update automatically.  Since I'm making 20 or more checkboxes in groupbox1, is there anyway simplify the code that would launch the update based on the entire groupbox having a checkedchanged rather than each individual checkbox running the update?  I actually spent a great deal of timing looking for something that would look like groupbox1.checkedchanged rather than checkbox1.checkedchanged

Comment: It seems that got the job done perfectly.  I was really surprised that it was so complicated to code what seems should be a relatively simple task (call update whenever groupbox1 contains a checked box). I would have never figured out that solution.  Clearly, I have a lot to learn.  Thanks again for your time.

Comment: Learning is part of the fun!    If you have a moment, could you please mark my answer as Accepted?